# Extending data from json in customDimensions

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I'm  using following code to send data to application insights

```ts
appInsights.trackEvent({
   name:'EventName',
   proprties:{'keys1':'value1' , 'key2':JSON.stringify({'nestedKey':'someValue'})}
});
```

when querying same in data explorer

```kql
customEvents
| extend key2_1 = parse_json(customDimensions.key2)
| extend key1_1 = tostring(customDimensions.key1)
| extend nestedKey1 = tostring(key2_1.nestedKey)
| extend nestedKey2 = tostring(customDimensions.key2.nestedKey)
```

both `nestedKey1`  and `nestedKey2` are null , but both `key1_1` and `key2_1` has data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the 2 lines:

```
| extend nestedKey1 = tostring(key2_1.nestedKey)
| extend nestedKey2 = tostring(customDimensions.key2.nestedKey)
```

with the following 2 lines:

```
| extend nestedKey1 = parse_json(tostring(key2_1)).nestedKey
| extend nestedKey2 = parse_json(tostring(parse_json(customDimensions.key2))).nestedKey
```

Here is the test result at my side:

[image]